# How to change new line character when editing existing files in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

To change the new line character for "New text file line delimiter" one would go to

Window -> Preferences -> General

Then change the "New text file line delimeter" to Windows, Unix or Max OS9.

I would like to know how to change the default line delimiter when editing existing files.

My co-worker uses a Mac and commits a Java class. I then check it out and add more code.
When I do a "git diff" my changes have meta-characters (^M). I presume they are carriage-return characters.

What setting can I use in Eclipse to always use Unix style new line characters not just for new text files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Preferences->General->Workspace.

Set Text file encoding to UTF-8.
Set line delimiter to Unix.

You could also configure GIT to not show the carriage return characters when doing a diff.

Add `whitespace = cr-at-eol` under the core section.

[This article](http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/04/06/windows-git-tip-hide-carriage-return-in-diff/) explains how to configure GIT for checking out, committing and Windows/Unix styles.

Comment: Although this didn't answer how to get Eclipse not to enter those carriage return characters it did help me not commit or see them in git. Thanks for the link km1.

Answer (score 5):

To convert the file that's open/exists:

File -> Convert Line Delimiters To -> Unix

Comment: The question is asking how to prevent the ^M from showing in git diff. Your suggestion will change every line which is the opposite of what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

For existing files, check the File menu when it's open in a text editor for actions to convert the line delimiters. Otherwise, the editor should already be respecting the line delimiter used in the file.

Git may also be changing the line delimiters based on how you've configured it. Did you accidentally set the git config core.autocrlf to `true`?

Comment: My git config file doesn't have autocrlf in it. When using the File menu to convert line delimiters it changes every line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences->General->Workspace;
There you have options "New Text file line delimiter"

Select Other -> Change Drop-down to Unix or what ever you want.

Comment: Isn't that what I said in the question? I know the option exists for "New text files". What about existing files? Also, what exactly does Eclipse mean by "text" files? Is a .java file considered a text file?